# Show thumbnail image in div on click / hover

Tags: jquery

Simply want to show the .thumbimage within the .fullsizeimage on click or hover - unfortunately no luck with the .attr function.

http://jsfiddle.net/CUZBa/ - Fiddle just in case!

```
 <div class="row">  
        <div class="fullsizeimage">
            <img src="https://www.houseplans.com/img/980e/461-2p1-2520_plan-detail.jpg" />
        </div>

    <div class="thumbimage"><a href="#"><img src="https://www.houseplans.com/img/85cd/461-2e-2520_plan-detail.jpg" width="100" height="100"></a></div>
    <div class="thumbimage"><a href="#"><img src="https://www.houseplans.com/img/872d/461-2alt1-2520_plan-detail.jpg" width="100" height="100"></a></div>
    <div class="thumbimage"><a href="#"><img src="https://www.houseplans.com/img/230e/461-2alt2-2520_plan-detail.jpg" width="100" height="100"></a></div>
</div>

<script src="" type="text/javascript">
$('.thumbimage a').on('click hover',function(){
    $('.fullsizeimage img').attr('src',$(this).attr('src'));
});
</script>
```

Comment: (you should put your events on the A-tag, not the IMG)

Comment: Simplified it to $('.thumbimage a') - code above updated, but it didnt seem to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `src=""` attribute from your `<script>` tag.

http://jsfiddle.net/CUZBa/6/

Comment: any idea on how to make this apply to the thumb image only?  $('.thumbimage a img').on('hover',function(){
     $('.fullsizeimage a img').attr('src',$(this).attr('src'));
 });

Answer (score 1):

1. Choose the jquery framework.
2. Remove script tag from your code